# using Pinia store with vue js i want the action to make subarrays in the returned data so that new data fetched from database wont be deleted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

using pinia store with firebase firestore and vuejs i want the action to make a new array inside an array that wont be deleted when the action is called with a different id like in my case paymentId

```
    import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
    import {
      collection, onSnapshot,where,
      query,orderBy,addDoc,deleteDoc,doc,updateDoc
    } from 'firebase/firestore'
    import {db} from '/src/js/firebase'
    import { useStoreAuth } from './storeAuth'
    import {today} from '@quasar/quasar-ui-qcalendar/src/index.js'
    import { uid } from 'quasar'
    import {useDynamicSort} from 'src/use/useDynamicSort'
    
    let paymentsCollectionRef
    let paymentsCollectionQuery
    let getPaymentsSnapshot=null
    
    export const useStorePayments= defineStore('storePayments', {
      state: () => {
    
        return {
           loadingPayments:false,
           payments:[],
           Mainpayments:[],
           transition:'',
           dayPayments:[],
           selectedDate:today()
        }
      },
    
 actions:{
    init(){
      const storeAuth=useStoreAuth()
      paymentsCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users',storeAuth.user.id,'payments')
   },
    async getPayments(id) {
      paymentsCollectionQuery = query(paymentsCollectionRef, where("patientid", "==",id),orderBy("date","desc"))
      this.loadingPayments=true
          getPaymentsSnapshot=onSnapshot(paymentsCollectionQuery, (querySnapshot) => {
          const payments=[]
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          let payment={
            id:doc.data().id,
            details:doc.data().details,
            date:doc.data().date,
            currencyhavetopay:doc.data().currencyhavetopay,
            currencypaid:doc.data().currencypaid,
            moneyhavetopay:doc.data().moneyhavetopay,
            moneypaid:doc.data().moneypaid,
            tooth:doc.data().tooth,
            doctor:doc.data().doctor,
            patientid:doc.data().patientid,
          }
          payments.push(payment)
          })

            this.Mainpayments=payments
       this.loadingPayments=false
        },error=>{
          console.log('error',error.message)

      })
   },

    
    
    })
```

so my problem is when the action fetching data array with specific id the Mainpayments array will be updated with the data containing that id but when i want to fetch data with new id the old array with previous id will be deleted and updated with the data with the new id and my question is could i make sub arrays for each data fetched from firestore inside the Mainpayments array with the name of the payment id ? so when new data with new id wont overwrite my previous array?

Comment: Sure.  Instead of `this.Mainpayments=payments` which overwrites Mainpayments every time, just do `this.Mainpayments.push(payments)`  I'm not sure how to interpret "make sub arrays ... with the name of the payment id".  Do all the `payment` objects within `payments` have the same id?  then you can do `this.Mainpayments.push({id: payments[0].id, payments: payments})`

Comment: ok but the problem with this live updates in firestore will cause addition of new array not updating the previous one so i want it to be equal a new array inside the mainPayments array any idea? or when pushing array if it's already exist it will be overwritten